# A simpler way to constraint the order of the arguments of a template

Tags: c++, templates, microcontroller

I want to connect a chip (IC) to a microcontroller. To do this I have to connect specific pins of the microcontroller to the IC. As I know the conection in compilation time the best way to do it is with a template:

```
template<int num_pin_a, int num_pin_b, int num_pin_c>
struct IC{
// ...
};
```

In this example my IC has 3 pins: A, B and C.

The problem with this code is that it is a little error prone. To create an IC I have to write

```
IC<14, 10, 7> my_ic;
```

But what is the meaning of 14, 10 and 7? I can't read this code, and I want to read my code. Of course I can use macros or constexpr to avoid magic numbers, and so I can read the code but the compiler can't. I want my compiler to inform me if a made a mistake.

In order to achieve this, I wrote the following code:

```
template<int n>
struct Pin_A{};

template<int n>
struct Pin_B{};

template<int n>
struct Pin_C{};

template<int num_pin_a, int num_pin_b, int num_pin_c>
IC<num_pin_a, num_pin_b, num_pin_c> ic(Pin_A<num_pin_a>, 
                                       Pin_B<num_pin_b>, 
                                       Pin_C<num_pin_c>)
{
    return IC<num_pin_a, num_pin_b, num_pin_c>{};
}
```

When I want to create an IC I have to write this code:

```
auto my_ic = ic(Pin_A<14>{}, Pin_B<10>{}, Pin_C<7>{});
```

and it is wonderfull because I can understand and the compiler also understand it. If, for instance, I change the order of the pins

```
auto my_ic = ic(Pin_A<14>{}, Pin_C<10>{}, Pin_B<7>{});
```

it won't compile.

But I was wondering if there is a simpler way to achieve the same thing. Do you know a better way?

Comment: Have you looked at using enums? Also, what are your compiler restrictions? I.e. there are some proposals in the latest C++ standards that deal with `constexpr` objects as a template arguments.

Comment: Have you heard about [enums](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)?

Comment: Please, elaborate. I don't want to enumerate my pins, I want to give an error at compile time if you pass that enum in an incorrect order. And how can you write `template <enum E> struct IC{...}`???

Comment: @DanM. My compiler restrictions? I'm sorry, I think I don't understand well. What I want is to make a hardware connection: pin A (a real wire) with pin 14 of my microcontroller (a real pin); pin B with pin 10 of my microcontroller and pin C with pin 7. As these are hardware connection is fundamental that they are in the right order. So I want my compiler to give me an error if, for mistake, I write my code in different order.

Comment: @Antonio I've meant what is your target compiler? Also, are yur Pins named? I.e. is Pin_A - pin number 14, or `Pin_A<14>` is a pin of class `A` number `14` (of which  there are several possible)?

Answer (score 0):

You might directly have something like:

```
template <typename, typename, typename> struct IC;

template<int a, int b, int c>
struct IC<Pin_A<a>, Pin_B<b>, Pin_C<c>>
{
    // ...
};
```